# How can I get uploaded image to display immediately after upload in a spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've looked through various questions on stack overflow dealing with this but haven't found any conclusive solution. So basically in my project currently, I have it so that a user can upload an image and the image then gets stored in the static/resources folder. I followed this tutorial when creating the file storage service:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files

My issue is that the file upload is successful but the uploaded image isn't viewable unless I reload the project, and that isn't really what I want it to do. I would prefer if when I upload an image, when the user goes back to the page the image is immediately viewable there. I've tried many of the solutions I found for it, such as uploading to a folder outside of static, but I'm not sure how to access these files in thymeleaf, another solution I found was to upload to the target folder, but unfortunately that didn't seem to work either and others.

The relevant files are below:

```
<div class="works" id="works" th:each="applications: ${applications}">
    <div class="works__item">
        <img class="works__photo" th:src="@{/images/services/{image}(image=${applications.imageName})}" alt="">
        <form th:action="@{/admin/evcharging}" th:method="get">
            <div class="works__content">
                <div class="works__title" th:text="${applications.applicationName}"></div>
                <div class="works__text" th:text="${applications.applicationType}"></div>
                <button class="btn btn--red btn--long">Learn more</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

The controller to create the attribute is below:

```
@GetMapping("/adminLanding")
public String adminLanding(Model model) {
    String currentUserName = "";
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (!(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
        currentUserName = authentication.getName();
    }
    if(!currentUserName.isEmpty()){
        List<Application> applications = applicationRepository.findByAdminAdminID(adminRepository.findByUsername(currentUserName).getAdminID());
        model.addAttribute("applications", applications);
    }
    return "adminLanding";
}
```

The storage properties are below:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("storage")
public class StorageProperties {
    private String location = "src/main/resources/static/images/services";

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

And this project was done on intellij if that is relevant.